# Can I avoid my subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

My structure is fairly simple:
I have `ways` that consist of multiple `points`. Each `point` has a x and y position. 
Ways are defined with the help of an extra table `wayspoints` which contains the columns `wid` and `pid`.

What I have to do is fetch all ways (with all of there points) within a certain distance to a given x and y.

I do this by checking the difference between the points x,y and the given x,y.

The problem I have is that I dont want just all points within the distance but rather all points that belong to each way that has points within the distance.

Before I had this requirement my query ran for about 100ms fetching 1 million points. Since I now need each way in its whole I added a subquery which now takes about 4-5 seconds to fetch.

This is unacceptable to me. Here is the sql (the numbers are the given x and y coordinates):

```
SELECT concat(WAYS.id, '|',WAYS.name) "id", POINTS.x, POINTS.y 
FROM WAYS, WAYPOINTS, POINTS 
WHERE WAYPOINTS.WID = WAYS.ID AND 
      WAYPOINTS.PID = POINTS.ID AND 
      WAYPOINTS.WID IN (SELECT w.ID 
                        FROM WAYS w, WAYPOINTS wp, POINTS p 
                        WHERE wp.WID = w.ID AND wp.PID = p.ID 
                        AND p.x < (51.739400 + 0.01) 
                        AND p.x > (51.739400 - 0.01)
                        AND p.y < (8.710202 + 0.01)
                        AND p.y > (8.710202 - 0.01);
```

If I could at least achieve max 1 second that would be nice. I know Im asking a lot since the solution is working already but I feel like there must be something I'm missing here..

PS: Ive added an Index to each column in question.

Comment: Is this mysql or sql-server? no tag spam please

Comment: Sorry I thought sql-server was a brief term for all mysql servers. Im using mysql.

Comment: You can avoid the subquery, but you'll have to use modern join notation.

Comment: @Uueerdo will it be significantly faster? I have no problem with using joins if they would improve my solution.

Comment: Well, technically you can probably get away with just using the archaic "comma" join notation, but the query would be ridiculously hard to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM points AS pWithin
INNER JOIN waypoints AS pwWP ON pWithin.ID = pwWP.PID
INNER JOIN way AS pwW ON pwWP.WID = pwW.ID
INNER JOIN waypoints AS wp ON pwW.ID = wp.WID
INNER JOIN points AS p ON wp.PID = p.ID
WHERE pWithin.x < (51.739400 + 0.01) 
   AND pWithin.x > (51.739400 - 0.01)
   AND pWithin.y < (8.710202 + 0.01)
   AND pWithin.y > (8.710202 - 0.01);
```

The `WHERE` and first reference to `points` finds the "points within the distance", the next two joins are used to find the ways those points are in, and the final two joins find the points within those ways.

*Obviously, you can replace `p.*` with the actual result data you want.*

Edit: One thing you may need to watch out for is if a `way` has multiple points "within the distance" it, and all it's points will show up multiple times. Simply changing `SELECT` to `SELECT DISTINCT` should remedy that easily though.

Comment: Great. Will this provide me with information from the other tables as well? The ´points´ table only contains x and y.

Comment: @ThatBrianDude Ah, yeah, you can get data from any of the joined tables in that query. `pWithin` will be the point that put the `pwW` way "within the distance", and `p` are the points on `pWithin`'s way.

Comment: Points are now showing up multiple times even with DISTINCT.  How can that be?

Comment: If the point is a waypoint for multiple ways, and more than one of those ways is "within the distance" it will appear once for each of those ways.

Comment: Yes but shouldnt `DISTINCT` take care of that? I am seeing about 5 instances of each point

Comment: `DISTINCT` takes care of distinct result rows; if you are selecting anything other than fields from `p` (_such as `pwW.id` and `pwW.name`_) the result may repeat `p` values with different values for those non-`p` fields. If you want only unique `p` data points, you'll need to not include fields from any of the other referenced tables; or group on the selected `p` fields and GROUP_CONCAT() the selected non-`p` fields.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, have you tried creating that subquery as a CTE?

For example you'd write something like

```
WITH (SELECT w.ID 
                    FROM WAYS w, WAYPOINTS wp, POINTS p 
                    WHERE wp.WID = w.ID AND wp.PID = p.ID 
                    AND p.x < (51.739400 + 0.01) 
                    AND p.x > (51.739400 - 0.01)
                    AND p.y < (8.710202 + 0.01)
                    AND p.y > (8.710202 - 0.01) as CTE
SELECT concat(WAYS.id, '|',WAYS.name) "id", POINTS.x, POINTS.y 
FROM WAYS, WAYPOINTS, POINTS, cte
WHERE WAYPOINTS.WID = WAYS.ID AND 
  WAYPOINTS.PID = POINTS.ID AND 
  WAYPOINTS.WID = cte.id
```

You'll want to compare the performance of your query to the CTE query;

To do so you'll write

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE ( 
*the entire query*
);
```

Comment: Im not familiar with the term, whats a CTE?

Comment: MySQL does not support CTEs

Answer (score 0):

Not positive this is what you are asking.
Try this though. You should only get the Waypoints where those point criteria are true anyways.

```
 SELECT concat(WAYS.id, '|',WAYS.name) "id", POINTS.x, POINTS.y 
    FROM WAYS, WAYPOINTS, POINTS 
    WHERE WAYPOINTS.WID = WAYS.ID AND 
          WAYPOINTS.PID = POINTS.ID AND 
          AND Points.x < (51.739400 + 0.01) 
          AND points.x > (51.739400 - 0.01)
          AND points.y < (8.710202 + 0.01)
          AND points.y > (8.710202 - 0.01);
```

Comment: That is what I had before I had to not only get each point within the radius but also all the points connected to the ways of those within the radius.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: Join on bridge-table, using exists(). This will avoid duplicates in the final result.

---

```
SELECT concat(w.id, '|',w.name) "id", p.x, p.y 
FROM WAYS w
JOIN POINTS p ON EXISTS ( -- Join on bridge-table
    SELECT * 
    FROM  WAYPOINTS wp
    WHERE wp.WID = w.ID 
    AND wp.PID = p.ID
    AND EXISTS ( -- waypoints that contain a particular point
            SELECT*
            FROM WAYPOINTS wp2
            JOIN  POINTS p2 ON wp2.PID = p2.ID
            WHERE wp2.WID = wp.WID -- same way as outer
            AND p2.x < 51.739400 + 0.01
            AND p2.x > 51.739400 - 0.01
            AND p2.y < 8.710202 + 0.01
            AND p2.y > 8.710202 - 0.01
            )
    );
```

Comment: Mysql appears to have a problem with EXISTS(). (or, maybe I forgot a condition somewhere ...)